# How to retrieve command line in some process in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Using the following code I can get the `CommandLine` of a process by passing the `PID`:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '11132'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

[image]

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '8260'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

[image]

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '9308'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

[image]

**BUT** the same command is not returning the `CommandLine` in some of the processes as shown here:

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '4208'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

[image]

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '3944'" | Select Name,ProcessId,CommandLine
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does a `service` have a `CommandLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If there's a *permissions-related* inability to retrieve certain processes' command lines, [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance)  `Win32_Process` *quietly ignores* the failure,  resulting in the `.CommandLine` property containing `$null`.

  - In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the same applies to the `.CommandLine` property of the objects output by [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) (this property isn't available in *Windows PowerShell*).
- Therefore, **to be able to query as many process command lines as possible, run your `Get-CimInstance` call from an *elevated* (run-as-admin) session**.

  - However, **even then a *select few* - presumably *system-owned* - processes can *not* be queried**, neither in terms of their *command line* nor in terms of their *user* (the identity of the user account owning the process), which `Get-Process` allows you to request via its `-IncludeUserName` switch.
  - To find those processes, run the following *from an elevated session*:

    ```bash
    Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Where-Object { -not $_.CommandLine }
    ```

---

Since the two service processes shown in your questions aren't system services, I would expect the following to work *when run with elevation*:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter 'Name = "TeamViewer_Service.exe" OR Name = "ErgonomicKBNotificationService.exe"' | 
  Select-Object ProcessId, Name, CommandLine
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check, if this PID even has a command line? Some tasks just don't have one:
[image]

Comment: I did and yes they have for sure